# how to add ability of drag@drop to icon on reactjs?

Tags: reactjs

I have simple code that i get from the 'create-react-app XXX'  ( xxx is the project name )

this is the simple code:

```
class App extends Component {
   render() {
      return (
        <div className="App">
          <header className="App-header">
             <h1 className="App-title">Need drag to here the react icon</h1>
          </header>
          <p className="App-intro">
            To get started  <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" /> , edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
          </p>
        </div>
      );
 }
  }

  export default App;
```

The ui look like this:

[image]

I trying to add ability of drad the reactjs icon on the header => that mean that i try to drag it on the black part of the screen

How to do it ?
I can't find simple way for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be very easy to do using html5 drag and drop api. You have to add the `draggable` attribute to the icon since you want it to be dragged and then you can use `Drag events` to achieve drag and drop of the icon on the black portion. Read more about it here: [drag and drop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_Drag_and_Drop_API). Check [this](https://github.com/zamhaq/vue-kanban) also, although this implementation is in vue, you will get an idea.

Comment: yes, in html i know how to do it .. very simple and nice. but i need to implement this in reactjs with minimum code. can't find a way without writing new component with all the dragTarget and other new component with dragSource

Comment: What do you mean by new components? you can do drag on drop on the above components.

Comment: Please explain .. i don't understand

Comment: Add `draggable` attribute to your `img`. Use the `dragStart` event to track element drag. Attach the listener for `drop` event on your h1. Now you basically need to put your image inside your `h1`. You should be able to find many examples on the web. Otherwise, go to the above mentioned resources in my answer.